# Combine angular project into spring mvc project

Tags: angular, spring, netbeans

I have a java spring project that was developed to supply Web API to be called by another angular project.
I would like to bring the angular project to become part of the java spring project so that when I compile / run it in NetBeans, I can get both compile and can be run from 1 web server only.
Is it possible to do that? What are the necessary steps that I need to perform to have both project merge into one and can be edit/updated easily using NetBeans as 1 project only.
Can any one help me?
I think that pom.xml file must at least be modified and most probably, the angular project should be inserted into proj01\src\main\webapp?

2. If both project has been merged into one, do I still need web API to communicate between angular and spring? or I can perform a direct call between angular and spring?

Comment: Have you done **any** research? This is a fairly common question.

Comment: As for question 2, if you were to theoretically drop the API, how do you think they would communicate without an API?

Comment: Dear Rich, I must admit I didn't make a lot of research on this. But so far I found various information but can not meet my need. I want to have a spring mvc(not spring booot) project that embedded angular for front end. So, when I compile the project and run, everything is compiled and run. No need to manage 2 separate project. That is all

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you're looking for? https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-angular-web

Comment: I think this article demonstrate on creating a spring boot application and an angular application.  The one that I want is to work on spring mvc 4.0 (not spring boot) and add in the angular in the webapp folder and when I run the project, both the spring and the angular are automatically compiled and run.